# Curl with Simple HTML DOM using Link Pagination

Tags: php, dom, curl

I want to combine Curl and Simple HTML DOM.

Both are working fine separately.

I want to curl a site and then I want to look into the inner data using DOM
with pagination page numbers.

I am using this code.

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

function dlPage($href) {
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $href);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $href);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.125 Safari/533.4");

    $str = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    // Create a DOM object
    $dom = new simple_html_dom();
    // Load HTML from a string
    $dom->load($str);

    return $dom;
}

$url = 'http://example.com/';
$data = dlPage($url);

// echo $data;

#######################################################

$startpage = 1;
$endpage = 3;

for ($p=$startpage;$p<=$endpage;$p++) {
    $html = file_get_html('http://example.com/page/$p.html');   
    // connect to main page links
    foreach ($html->find('div#link a') as $link) {  
        $linkHref = $link->href;
        //loop through each link
        $linkHtml = file_get_html($linkHref);
        // parsing inner data
        foreach($linkHtml->find('h1') as $title) {          
            echo $title;
        } 
        foreach ($linkHtml->find('div#data') as $description) {
            echo $description;
        }
    }
 }
?>
```

How can I combine this to make it work as one single script?